# Set icon to JLabel - not display icon

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

My code:

```
public class UserDialog extends JDialog {

    public UserDialog() {
    add(createForm(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(400, 100);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

    public JPanel createForm() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Check.png");

    okBtn = new JButton("Ok");
    cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
    tempBtn = new JLabel();
    fNameLbl = new JLabel("First Name");
    fNamePicLbl = new JLabel(image);     // add icon to jlable
    lNameLbl = new JLabel("Last Name");
    lNamePicLbl = new JLabel();
    genderLbl = new JLabel("Gender");

    maleRb = new JRadioButton("Male");
    femaleRb = new JRadioButton("Female");
    temp3 = new JLabel();
    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(maleRb);
    group.add(femaleRb);

    fNameTf = new JTextField(10);
    lNameTf = new JTextField(10);

    panel.add(fNameLbl);
    panel.add(fNameTf);
    panel.add(fNamePicLbl);
    panel.add(lNameLbl);
    panel.add(lNameTf);
    panel.add(lNamePicLbl);
    panel.add(genderLbl);
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    radioPanel.add(maleRb);
    radioPanel.add(femaleRb);
    panel.add(radioPanel);
    panel.add(temp3);
    panel.add(okBtn);
    okBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(cancelBtn);
    cancelBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(tempBtn);

    panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 4, 3, 50, 10, 80, 60);
    return panel;
}
```

When i run program, icon not display.

Comment: ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Check.png"); isn't valid path

Comment: @mKorbel The `Check.png` is in my workplace folder.

Comment: @mKorbel  I think a path that might not **exist**, can still be **valid.**  But yes, it seems the image file is not being found, like the situation in around 3 other questions *every day*..  OP - By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: @Sajjad you can to simply test for if (image == null) ....

Comment: @mKorbel i test it, But it is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an issue with path of Check.png. Correct the path and icon shall appear. 
If icon is stored under resource folder icons then path should be like below.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("icons/Check.png");
```

Comment: Can you please share tentative project structure.

Comment: My project is in here: `C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\src\Project`

Comment: If icon is outside project folder try with absolute path, else try entering relative path from src folder.

Comment: And my image is in here: `C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\src\Project`

Comment: How can change my workplace folder? I think that it can be solve problem.

Comment: try this out  ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\src\Project\icons\Check.png");

Comment: In here: `C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\src\Project\Check.png`, Thanks.

Comment: This is a poor 'fix' in that it is very fragile and will break when the app. is deployed in a Jar.

Comment: Rightly said Andrew, as mentioned in initial post icon should be within project and should be configured as relative path.